# Remove elements from a list while it's being iterated in a xhtml page using <a4j:repeat>

Tags: java, jsf, arraylist

I'd like to show the names of `Authors` from a list called `documentAuthorBeanToShow`. I'm showing them in `inputtexts` and I'm showing a `button` to remove each `Author` showed. When I click the button I'd like to remove the `Author` from the `list` and remove it from the view automatically.

The problem is: When I click the button, I get the exception:

```
HTTP STATUS 500 - java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
```

I've checked some links here, and discovered I need to use the method `Iterator.remove()` to remove elements from a list while it's being iterated. But my problem is about JSF. I don't know how to use an iterator in the xhtml page. What's the best way to do that simple task I'm trying to?

**EDITED - NOW USING Iterator.remove(). With the code below I don't get the exception described above. To have it working properly, it's just necessary to add the property described on the answer I choose.**

Look at the code:

**xhtml**

```
 <a4j:repeat value="#{editDocController.documentAuthorsBeanToShow}" var="author" >
            <br />
            <h:inputText value="#{author.name}" disabled="true" />
             <h:commandButton type="submit" action="#{editDocController.removeAutor(author.uri)}" value="Remover" />
             <br />
          </a4j:repeat>
```

**editDocController**

```
public void removeAutor(String uri) {   
   Iterator<AuthorBean> itAuthorBean = this.documentAuthorsBeanToShow.iterator();   
     while(itAuthorBean.hasNext()) {
         AuthorBean a = itAuthorBean.next();
         if(a.getUri().equals(uri)) {
             itAuthorBean.remove();
         }
     }

 }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can help you, I put the zone that you wanna refresh into a a4j:outPutpanel with an id, then change the commandButton for a4j:commandButton with an action and specify  the zone that you wanna rerender, take a look  at this poor example :

```
<a4j:outputPanel id="panellImatge">
<!-- here a4j:repeat...whatever-->
<a4j:commandButton  styleClass="button"   action = "yourControllertoremove"   reRender="panellImatge"/>
</a4j:ouPutPanel>
```

I hope it helps.

So in you controller you remove the elements.

Comment: your welcome, i hope apologize my english...@Flying dumping tell us maybe I don't put everything, just to make an idea.

Comment: @Luciane Sorry i didn't realize from your method code that you already used `Iterator` to remove elements from list. See my answer and its comments.

Comment: I checked. After I remove the element from the List, I removed from the database, and it was removed. But I think that's because I forgot to edit the remove method in my post. After I posted it, I've already changed the method to use the iterator.remove() method. Will edit....

Answer (score 2):

Use `Iterator` in your `removeAutor()` method.

```
public void removeAutor(String uri) {
    Iterator<AuthorBean> iterator = documentAuthorsBeanToShow.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        if(iterator.next().getUri().equals(uri)){
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I did it. My problem was how to deal with it in the JSF page. Thank you!